# What does "Unable to read EDID for display device" mean?

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Today I checked my system logs and I found a spam of this line:

```
[ 11972.301] (WW) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Unable to read EDID for display device CRT-0
```

Im on an acer aspire 5742G laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GT540M graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That message means that your VGA-card couldn't get the EDID info from you CRT monitor (or it can be also an LCD connected with VGA-cable). The EDID tells the video card about the capabilities of the monitor (resolutions, frequencies, etc.) More info about EDID on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data).

You can see the EDID info in linux if you run

```
xrandr --verbose
```

Because you have a laptop you will likely see the EDID for your internal LCD screen Hopefully that one didn't fail.

It is likely that the faulty in this situation is not your nvidia card, but your CRT monitor. It is also possible that the CRT monitor doesn't have a serious problem, it just has a problem with sending the EDID. (It is also possible that if it is an LCD monitor connected with VGA cable, that it just simply don't send its EDID info through VGA, and it has absolutely no problems)  You can use your card and CRT monitor without the EDID info, the only problem in this case that you will have to manually set up the available resolutions, frequencies, etc. (If you set something what is not suitable for your monitor, then it can damage your monitor.)